# Sending AJAX POST to PHP is not working?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I swear this was working properly earlier, but now it's not so I clearly messed something up.

I'm making a form where the inputted info gets AJAX posted to my PHP file, which just outputs the username and password. Right now I even hardcoded the data being sent to just a string and the php file just printing that for testing purposes. However, when I click submit, it doesn't go to my loginProcess.php page, but it just stays on the page and prints to the console "hello","success", and "test", which indicates it went through the full `Process()` function.

My url is correct and in the same directory as the index.html file. I've tried different things such as using `$.post()` or making the submit button a `type="input"`. If you see the `form` line I commented out before the non-commented one, that's me trying to send the data directly without going through ajax and it works fine and outputs the loginProcess.php (however my project requires going through ajax). Anyone know what's going on?

Here's my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <!-- <script src="frontEnd.js"></script> -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>      
<title>Login System</title>
</head>
<style>
</style>

<body>
    <center>
        <p><b>LOGIN SYSTEM</b></p>
        <!-- <form id="login" action ="loginProcess.php" method="post">  -->
        <form name = "loginform">
            UCID:<br>
            <input type="text" name="username"><br>
            Password:<br>
            <input type="password" name="password"><br><br>
            <button type="button" onclick = "Process()">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </center>


</body>
 <script>
    function Process() {
        console.log("hello")
        var ucid = document.loginform.username.value;
        var pw = document.loginform.password.value;
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: "loginProcess.php",
            data: "ajaxUCID=TESTUSERNAME",
            success: function(){
                console.log("success")
            },
            error: function(){
                console.log("error")
            }
        });
        // $.post("loginProcess.php",{ajaxUCID:"TESTUSERNAME"});
        console.log("test")
    }
 </script>
```

Here's my loginProcess.php file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>process</title></head>
<body>
<?php
$ucidPHP = $_POST["ajaxUCID"];
echo "Username is ".$ucidPHP;

// $pwPHP = $_POST["ajaxPW"];
// echo "Password is ".$pwPHP;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the error u get ?

Comment: put data like {"ajaxUCID":"TESTUSERNAME"};

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
 <script>
    function Process() {
        var ucid = document.loginform.username.value;
        var pw   = document.loginform.password.value;
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: "loginProcess.php",
            data: {ajaxUCID:TESTUSERNAME},
            success: function(){
                console.log("success")
            },
            error: function(){
                console.log("error")
            }
        });
    }
 </script>
```

Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on your network tab of Google chrome or equivalent of the other browser and then send your Ajax request to observe your packet delivered what result do you have ?

If you have a packet with an error can you tell us witch one, and if you receive a good header (without errors) , check the information inside it to see if it throws correct informations, like the data form in your Ajax post.

After that if the information are correct and the data structure is correct, to test, I usually do the following code to test the entire post received :

```
if(isset($_POST)){
  var_dump($_POST); // this will show all posts received 
}
```

Let me know if it works for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't get your problem, the code is working with me and returning the result successfully.

I think you mean that why the returned results doesn't show on the same page of the form.

Here is the correct code and below it is the explanation

**index.php**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <!-- <script src="frontEnd.js"></script> -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>      
<title>Login System</title>
</head>
<style>
</style>

<body>
    <center>
        <p><b>LOGIN SYSTEM</b></p>
        <!-- <form id="login" action ="loginProcess.php" method="post">  -->
        <form name = "loginform">
            UCID:<br>
            <input type="text" name="username"><br>
            Password:<br>
            <input type="password" name="password"><br><br>
            <button type="button" onclick = "Process()">Submit</button>
        </form>
    <div id="responseFromServer"></div>
    </center>


</body>
 <script>
    function Process() {
        console.log("hello")
        var ucid = document.loginform.username.value;
        var pw = document.loginform.password.value;
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: "loginProcess.php",
            data: {"ajaxUCID":ucid},
            success: function(response){
        document.getElementById("responseFromServer").innerHTML =   response;
                console.log("success")
            },
            error: function(){
                console.log("error")
            }
        });
        // $.post("loginProcess.php",{ajaxUCID:"TESTUSERNAME"});
        console.log("test")
    }
 </script>
```

the code you provided was actually working properly, its just you didn't pick the result to display it on your page. 
that was done by adding a `div` where I will place the response.

```
    <div id="responseFromServer"></div>
```

and in the success callback of the ajax call, I just catched the response sent back from the server and placed it right inside the div, like so:

```
        document.getElementById("responseFromServer").innerHTML =   response;
```

That should work

**Update#1:**
He wanted to redirect to the php page.

in plain English, you should use ajax requests when you want to work with the server, send requests or get results without reloading the page, you can read more here [Getting Starting with AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started)

> AJAX stands for Asynchronous JavaScript And XML. In a nutshell, it is the use of the XMLHttpRequest object to communicate with servers. It can send and receive information in various formats, including JSON, XML, HTML, and text files. AJAX’s most appealing characteristic is its "asynchronous" nature, which means it can communicate with the server, exchange data, and update the page without having to refresh the page.

so in your case that you want to **redirect** the user, you don't really want to use ajax in this case you can simply do that with plain html form tag.

a form tag can have multiple attributes, here we are concerned with 2 :

1. action
2. method

Here is how you can update the code to get to your results

first: the form part:

```
<form name = "loginform" method="POST" action="loginProcess.php">
            UCID:<br>
            <input type="text" name="ajaxUCID"><br>
            Password:<br>
            <input type="password" name="password"><br><br>
            <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
        </form>
```

I've added 2 attributes, which are:

1. method: I set it to POST, because this is the http request type which you accept on your server [your PHP file you used $_POST].
2. action: I set it to the relative path of the file which should recieve your request, in our case its "loginProcess.php"

Then I changed the name of the input where we enter the username or UCID to be the same as the one you are receiving in your PHP file. 
in your php you were accepting a request parameter `$_POST["ajaxUCID"]` this means that you are accepting a POST request and you want a parameter called ajaxUCID , that must be the name of the input. this is why I did that `<input type="text" name="ajaxUCID">`

I have also stopped the onClick action on the button to prevent the ajax request, also I have changed its type to "submit" so that once its clicked, it will automatically submit the form for you.

I hope that helped now, if you need furthur help, leave a comment

Comment: Hmm that does work and it shows the output in a black box that I have to highlight. Here's a screenshot https://gyazo.com/ed20dd5b552ea6ccc274e28df0122d2d .                                            But this was my intended output, it would go to the page that my loginProcess.php had. Here's what it looks like when I skip the AJAX request and directly go to loginProcess.php on button submit (what I was expecting with AJAX too) https://gyazo.com/168bf78fc5c0021f03379ce9e0266713

Comment: That black box was because I had my div stylized (sorry about that), but regardless I thought it would go to a new page with just that string like I have in the second screenshot?

Comment: see, in plain english, you should use ajax requests only if you intend to send a request to your server and get the result while you are on the same page, BUT , if your intention is to redirect the user to another page, then you simply put the action attribute on the form request . I will update the answer so that you get the point